Sorry, this installer does not support your operating system: MSYS_NT-10.0-22631
I'm attempting to install Wasp, a tool for building full-stack web applications with React & Node.js.
The installation instructions recommend using the provided command:
curl -sSL https://get.wasp-lang.dev/installer.sh | sh

However, upon running this command, I receive an error message

Sorry, this installer does not support your operating system: MSYS_NT-10.0-22631.

